# Query taking a very long time

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have the following query to return userids that are not in the message_log table

```
select * from likes where userid not in(select to_id from message_log)
```

I have an index on the userid column in the likes table and an index on the to_id column in the message_log table but the index are not being used according to EXPLAIN. Is something wrong with my query? My query has been running for 20 minutes and still no results.

Comment: perhaps you have way too many rows? Consider using `join`

Comment: Should I be using left join or inner join?

Comment: Should be left join, because you want to include everything from the `likes` though it does not exist in the `message_log`. But just curious, how many rows do you have?

Comment: Not enough information. How many rows in each table and how many distinct key values (`userid`, `to_id`) in each table?

Comment: The rows are a million to a few million rows in each table

Comment: OK, that is probably way too many... I guess you want to check if your query works first for at least a couple of items then test which among your working query are the fastest before you apply it to your million x millions rows..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
select * from likes lk where not exists (select 1 from message_log where to_id = lk.userid )
```

Comment: The first one returns nothing, and the second one gives this error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_id"
LINE 1: ...elect * from likes left join message_log ml on ml to_id=like...
                                                             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_id"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 53

Comment: My query which took 30 minutes to execute returns 64742 rows, but the one with join that you posted returns 138095 rows

Comment: you have duplicate userid ?

Comment: not in the likes table, but the message_log table could contain multiple to_ids of the same value

Comment: try first one query now

Comment: I think the first one works fine. It returned the same amount of rows as my query, but only in 7 seconds compared to 30 minutes. Remove the second query and I'll accept this answer

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from likes 
     left join message_log ml on ml.to_id=likes.userid
where ml.to_id is null
```

Try the query with LEFT JOIN instead and leave the only userids without mesages

Comment: I get this error

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "to_id"
LINE 3:      left join message_log ml on ml to_id=likes.userid
                                            ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "to_id"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 61

Comment: Returns no rows at all

Answer (score 1):

First thing you should consider is turning the sub query into join. Like this: `select like.col1, like.col2
from likes like 
left join message_log mlog 
 on  like.userid = mlog.to_id 
where mlog.to_id is null`
Although optimizer will very likely do that for you.

Another thing you should try is to get rid of the asterisk from the select clause (as in my example) as it may impact indexes using by the optimizer.